# How to create complicated loops

Tags: r

I am stuck with creating loops for the following task.

1. The question asks that x & y are integers 1 through 100.
2. How many unique powers, x^y, are there?
3. I have learned about the basic loops but I don't know where to begin.

It would be helpful to get some advise.

Comment: When reading the title of this question I was only thinking: **Don't!**

Answer (score 3):

Use `outer`:

```
length(unique(as.vector(outer(1:100, 1:100, "^"))))
#[1] 9308
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop for this. Instead use `lapply`, which operates similarly to a loop:

```
length(unique(unlist(lapply(1L:100L, function(x) (1L:100L)^x))))
```

Breaking this out:

```
# apply the exponents 1:100 to all values 1:100
vallist <- lapply(1L:100L, function(x) (1L:100L)^x)
# form one vector and find all unique values from it:
u <- unique(unlist(vallist))
# number of unique values:
length(u)
```

Comment: @Roland True, but it's a loop in compiled C code, so that would not be obvious to a novice R user.

Comment: Yes, it's a hidden loop, but it's important to note that its performance is not better than a `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland Yes, good to point out. I like your solution better, anyway.